# How To Get 10 Number From The User And Print Out The Two Max Numbers

Tags: java

How To Get 10 Number From The User And Print Out The Two Max Numbers ?? i try to make a program that take 10 numbers from the user... and after its take 10 number its will show the maximum number of the numbers you entered and will show the number that was the higher before the maximum ( The Two Highest Numbers From The 10 Numbers You Entered ) i cant figure out why its not working .. ty all !!

```
import java.util.Scanner;


    public class E11 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  

            System.out.println("Enter Number " +0 +" : " );
            float scanNumTwo = scan.nextFloat();

            float scanNum = scanNumTwo;
            float lastscan ;
            float maxim = scanNumTwo;
            float lastmax = scanNumTwo;

            for(int i = 1 ; i<=9 ; i++){
                System.out.println("The Last Max " +lastmax +" : " );
                System.out.println("The Maximum Numer Is : "+maxim);

                System.out.println("Enter Number " +i +" : " );
                lastscan = scanNum;
                scanNum = scan.nextFloat();

                if(lastscan >= scanNum && lastscan >= maxim){
                    maxim = lastscan;
                }
                else if(scanNum >= lastscan && scanNum >= maxim){
                    maxim = scanNum;
                }

                else if (scanNum>lastscan && maxim>lastmax){
                    lastmax = lastscan;
                }
                else if (scanNum>lastmax && maxim>lastmax){
                    lastmax = scanNum;
                }

                System.out.println("The Maximum Numer Is : "+lastmax);
                System.out.println("The Maximum Numer Is : "+maxim);




        }
            System.out.println("The Maximum Numer Is : "+lastmax);
            System.out.println("The Maximum Numer Is : "+maxim);


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of the two biggest numbers. You can initialize them like this:

```
float maxNumb = scan.nextFloat();
float secondMax = scan.nextFloat();
if (secondMax > maxNumb) {
   float temp = maxNumb;
   maxNumb = secondMax;
   secondMax = temp;
}
```

After that, you can scan all the numbers (no print included for ease of reading):

```
for (...) {
   float next = scan.nextFloat();
   // if greater than max, then it's the new max and the old max is the 2nd
   if (next > maxNumb) {
     secondMax = maxNumb;
     maxNumb = next;
   }
   // if it's only greater than the second, then it's the new second.
   else if (next > secondMax) {
     secondMax = next;
   }
}
```